# WebAudioAPI: Dividing two AudioNodes' outputs

Tags: javascript, math, signal-processing, web-audio-api

Context: I am trying to implement an ADSR envelope in WebAudioAPI where Attack, Decay, Sustain and Release are all `AudioParams`, and the 'note on' and 'note off' is represented by an input value of 1 and 0 respectively. I'm using four `DynamicCompressor` nodes and a lot of gain manipulation to achieve this, since compressors are technically Attack-Release envelopes.

Everything is going fine, except for the fact that I need to divide the level of one signal by the level of another signal to get the amount of gain to achieve the level offset combined with the DynamicCompressor that produces the decay gradient.

If it helps, here's the formula:

```
decayOffsetY = (1 - sustainLevel) * (attackDur + decayDur) / decayDur
```

Note that `sustainLevel`, `attackDur` and `decayDur` are all AudioParams.

Addition, subtraction and multiplication are all rather easily achievable using some `ConstantSourceNodes` and `GainNodes`, but how do I go about division?

Note: I've thought about using another `DynamicCompressorNode` to perform the division, since compressors technically divide the signal by a ratio, but this ratio is in the logarithmic scale, and I end up with a compression ratio of

```
log(decayDur) / 5
```

to achieve the value of `1 / decayDur` which will be connected to another `GainNode`. But is it even possible to perform a `Math.log` using just AudioNodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `WaveShaperNode` to compute either the inverse or the log.  You'll have to figure out how to handle the case where the input is near zero and also how long to make the wave shaper curve array, but this should work.

Comment: Wow I completely overlooked the waveshaper as just a distortion tool. I understand that the `WaveShaperNode` input is limited to the range of -1 to 1, but does this limit also apply to the output as well?

Comment: Good question. The output is not limited to the same range; it should be arbitrary, more or less.